# resolved : aws lambda function not able to create a new instance with a fresh environment each time it is invoked

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I want my java aws lambda function to create a new instance each time it is invoked with a fresh environment.

But as of now it is reusing an existing aws lambda instance which is already created.

I tried setting AWS_LAMBDA_INITIALIZATION_TYPE environment variable to "on-demand" but it doesn't work.

How to achieve the desired outcome.

**Edit** : Rather than trying to change aws lambda initialization I solved the underlying usecase.

**Usecase** : I was trying to dynamically compile and get java class from source code text using net.openhft CachedCompiler.

But once compiled it was returning the same class from cache even if source code was changed. I used a different loader which forced it to recompile the code and build class each time.
So issue was resolved.

Comment: what's the use case? Why do you want a new instance each time?

Comment: WHat is a new Lambda instance.  If you want the community help - you should specify the Java Lambda code you are trying to use

Comment: If your code requires a new environment every time then it is not suitable for a Lambda - that is the antithesis of how to use Lambda.  Please explain your use case better.

Answer (score 2):

> as of now it is reusing an existing aws lambda instance which is already created

this is how lambda is meant to behave.  It reduces overhead for AWS and startup time for you on subsequent invocations

> I tried setting AWS_LAMBDA_INITIALIZATION_TYPE environment variable to "on-demand" but it doesn't work.

The environment variable *exposes* that setting.  It doesn't *control* that setting.  anyway, `on-demand` doesn't make the function be invoked only one time.

> I want my java aws lambda function to create a new instance each time it is invoked with a fresh environment.

Change your implementation so that the lambda can be invoked multiple times.